# Toast Message Vue Bootstrap Link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, toast

I'm using [vue-bootstrap-toasts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-toasts) ([demo](https://rakk7.github.io/vue-bootstrap-toasts/demo/)) to show Toasts on my site.

Now I want to put a link on that toast that leads to another side but it does not seem to work.

```
this.$toast.success('Test ist angelegt', {
  href: "www.google.de",
  rtl: true,
  timeOut: 8000
})
```

Do you have any suggestions for me or other solutions?

Comment: Looking through the source-code for this package, [it doesn't set the text with `v-html`](https://github.com/rakk7/vue-bootstrap-toasts/blob/master/src/components/Toasts.vue#L37) so you can't do this. If you're using Vue 3, [I've built a plugin which allows you to do this.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-dk-toast)

Comment: You probably need `https://` in the `href` value, or it'll try to visit `https://your-website.com/www.google.de`.

Comment: thanksfor the answer. You are right, i neet to set https:// 
Also fixed it with another lib, using vue-toasted witch allows to set actions for example onClick.

Answer (score 2):

Even through i got some downvotes i want to share my solution.

I installed vue-toasted and put this in my main.js file:

```
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted';

Vue.use(Toasted);
```

I now show my Toast like this:

```
this.$toasted.success('XYZ wurde angelegt: ', {

                    action: {

                      text : "My-Key",

                      onClick : () => {

                        window.open("https://my-site.de/my-key", "_self");

                    }

                }

              }).goAway(8000)
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://medium.com/dont-leave-me-out-in-the-code/toasts-in-vue-bootstrap-8b7772b64fed) solution:
"If we want to make an interactive toast (for accessibility reasons, Vue Bootstrap does not recommend making toasts interactive), we need to pass a component into the toast. First, I will create a super simple component called “TestButton.” If the user clicks on this button, the user will be routed to the ‘/home’ page"

```
<template>
  <div @click="navigate('/home')">
      test
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['type'],
    methods: {
        navigate(path) {
            this.$router.push(path);
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

"Second, we need to create a virtual element based on this component so that we can pass it into the toast. We call this.$createElement() and pass in our component with our props. Then, we pass in our virtual element into this.$bvToast.toast(). Now, if the user clicks on the body, the user will be routed to ‘/home.’"

```
const virtualElement = this.$createElement(ToastButton, {
  props: {
    type: 'testing'
  }
})
this.$bvToast.toast([virtualElement], {
  title: payload.notification.title,
  toaster: 'b-toaster-bottom-right',
  solid: true,
  appendToast: true
})
```